# how to send many emails in one time by php

Tags: php

i want know
how i can send one mail to 200 user
and i want when the email sendt
it appeare send to:user@mail.com 
from:my mail

because i think i see many email like that
to:email1@exaple.com;email2@exaple.com;emial3@exaple.com;
ithink this from bbc

i mean i want every user see sent to this email only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the native mail() function, separate the addresses with a comma, and put them all in the blind carbon copy list with additional headers.

```
$to       = "jon@abc.com,sal@example.com";
$subject  = "Mini-mass Emailer";
$message  = "Hello World";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: Your Name <me@mydomain.com>' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: {$to}' . "\r\n";

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Or you could iterate over the collection of email addresses and send each message individually:

```
$emails = array("foo@bar.com","fizz@buzz.com");
foreach ($emails as $email) {
  $to = $email;
  $subject = "My Subject";
  $message = "Hello World";

  mail($to, $subject, $message);
}
```

Comment: and will appear to:only uer mail or all emails

Comment: what the meaning of Blind carbon

Comment: and i think the second method will increase server load

Answer (score 1):

if use mail function

use bcc in header
like this :

```
$headers .= 'Bcc: 1@example.com,2@example.com.............' . "\r\n";
```

u can use a class like phpmailer
and use AddBCC() function

Answer (score 1):

Send each mail separately to each user. You can write a helper utility function to do this iteratively.